# Can we show two values together in a select box dropdown?

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu, angular-material, dropdown

[image reference](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dh0CY.png)
I want to show two values is one select box
my code :-

```
<mat-label for="property">Select property</mat-label>
<mat-select class="form-control" formControlName="property" id="property" disableOptionCentering
    panelClass="matSelect-class">
    <option value="" selected> -Select option- </option>
    <mat-option [value]="item.id">
        <span class="dropdown-name">Name</span>
        <span class="dropdown-address">address</span>
    </mat-option>
</mat-select>
```

Answer (score 0):

What about putting the description in an attribute e.g. title?

```js
$(function(){
  $("select").select2({
    templateResult: formatOption
  });
  
  function formatOption (option) {
    var $option = $(
      '<div><strong>' + option.text + '</strong></div><div>' + option.title + '</div>'
    );
    return $option;
  };
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"
integrity="sha256-CSXorXvZcTkaix6Yvo6HppcZGetbYMGWSFlBw8HfCJo="
crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.12/js/select2.full.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/select2@4.0.13/dist/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<select style="width:200px">
  <option value="optionA" title="Description for A">option A</option>
  <option value="optionB" title="Description for B">option B</option>
</select>
```

Comment: @shubham is this fix your question?